# Rails - Paperclip not working with AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

Paperclip is working without AWS, but when I try to use S3 storage it breaks.

```
#production.rb
    config.paperclip_defaults = {
        storage: :s3,
        s3_region: ENV["AWS_REGION"],
        s3_credentials: {
          # s3_host_name: ENV["AWS_HOST_NAME"],
          bucket: ENV["S3_BUCKET_NAME"],
          access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
          secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
          }
  }

    config.paperclip_defaults = { s3_host_name: "s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com", }
    # Added this line to fix: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

Before adding the last line I got an S3 error (`The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.`). After adding it the files get uploaded to local storage instead of S3.

I've also tried adding these to paperclip.rb, with different errors. When I add all 3 lines I get the error `Read-only file system @ dir_s_mkdir - /projects`

```
#paperclip.rb
# Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
# Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
#
# Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com'
```

Gemfile:

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'
```

I've also tried `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` which didn't seem to help

edit:
AWS_HOST_NAME: s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com

AWS_REGION: us-west-1

S3_BUCKET_NAME: groundwork-images-2

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ...

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ...

I've setup IAM account and created the bucket in the us-west-1 region. Is there anything on S3 that I need to do to add permissions?

I can't understand why Paperclip is storing it locally, with out any errors or anything if the config is for S3..

Comment: Did this happen yesterday?

Comment: It's still happening. I don't think it has to do with the S3 outage

Comment: It was worth a shot. Would you kindly add the error message you are receiving from S3? Also, the last line you added, did you add that below the first config setting, in the `production.rb`?

Comment: Edited to add the 2 different errors I'm seeing

Comment: Your config looks solid... I would do two things: 1) add `s3_host_name` to the initial config hash, otherwise, it looks like you are just overriding the initial configuration settings. 2) confirm your ENV vars are correct and that you created the bucket in the correct region, `US Standard`.

Comment: The ENV variables look correct. My bucket is in `us-west-1`. Adding `s3_host_name` back to the config gives the same errors. Should the host url be `apigateway.us-west-1.amazonaws.com`? from: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html  Does Paperclip default back to local storage if S3 fails? I'm not sure why it would be storing it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now

Here is the code I used:

```
#production.rb
    config.paperclip_defaults = {
        storage: :s3,
        s3_region: ENV["AWS_REGION"],
            s3_host_name: "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
        s3_credentials: {
          # s3_host_name: ENV["AWS_HOST_NAME"],
          bucket: ENV["S3_BUCKET_NAME"],
          access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
          secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
          }
  }
```

@meagar pointed out that I needed to combine the 2 config statements. I also uploaded an image to the S3 bucket to double check bucket name/region. And I recreated IAM credentials.